# google places api references field

Tags: iphone, ios, google-places-api

This is related to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681662/google-places-api-is-the-reference-field-reliable

Which had no answers, hopefully I'll have better luck.

There doesn't seem to be much documentation about the persistence of the reference field from the Places API result. This uniquely identifies a place, and works fine for now, but under what conditions could this change? And if it does, what does the json result look like?

Basically I want to cut the amount of work my app does by first caching up the references for all the places I'm interested in, and then do Details API queries based on those references (instead of searching for them every time).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interestingly, I've managed to get 2 different reference ids for exactly the same place. The JSON object retrieved when doing a details search returns the same object like-for-like (except for the reference field, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arg. Hate it when this happens (look stupid for asking the question in the first place)... answer is in the docs..

From: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

reference contains a unique token that you can use to retrieve additional information about this place in a Place Details request. **You can store this token and use it at any time in future to refresh cached data about this Place, but the same token is not guaranteed to be returned for any given Place across different searches.**